# Installing readline 6.0 on OS X

Tags: macos, installation, readline

I'm trying to install readline 6 from source but run into an error during 'make install'.

Here is the end of the output after executing 'sudo make install'

```
( cd shlib ; make  DESTDIR= install )
/bin/sh ../support/mkdirs /usr/local/lib
/bin/sh ../support/shlib-install -O darwin9.7.0 -d /usr/local/lib -b /usr/local/bin -i "/usr/bin/install -c -m 644" libhistory.6.0.dylib
/bin/sh ../support/shlib-install -O darwin9.7.0 -d /usr/local/lib -b /usr/local/bin -i "/usr/bin/install -c -m 644" libreadline.6.0.dylib
install: you may need to run ldconfig
```

I know that `ldconfig` isn't installed by default on OS X, and I read somewhere that it shouldn't be needed to fix this issue. I believe it has something to do with dynamic libraries, but I haven't been able to find out how to fix the issue, anyone have any insight?

FYI, I'm running OS X on an intel 2.4ghz macbook

thanks

P.S. I also applied the 3 available readline 6 patches before running configure and make

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, this isn't an error at all... it's just a notice message at the end of the install. It get this too, and my readline 6 is happily installed.

If you check `/usr/local/lib` and see readline there, you're done :-) No need to run any equivalent of ldconfig.

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib | grep readline
libreadline.6.0.dylib
libreadline.6.dylib
libreadline.a
libreadline.dylib
```